# How to access Jersey's contextual objects in an aspect when using Spring?

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects, spring-jersey

I am working with Spring 5.2.x together with Jersey 2.30.x for JAX-RS.

I have an annotation as following:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

In my service, I use this annotation as following:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @MyAnnotation
    public Response get() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to execute certain logic when the `@MyAnnotation` annotation is present. For this, I created an aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Context
    private ContainerRequest request;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(so.MyAnnotation)")
    public void annotated() {
    }

    @Before("annotated()")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("I need access to the HTTP headers: " + request);
    }
}
```

In this aspect, I need access to the HTTP headers. I tried injecting Jersey's `ContainerRequest`, but this seems to fail: the reference is always `null`.

So my question is: how can I access Jersey's contextual objects, such as `ContainerRequest`, in Spring's managed beans?

## minimal example

I created a minimal example, see https://github.com/pbillen/playground-so-61750237. You can build it with `mvn clean install -U` and then start a Tomcat container with `mvn cargo:run`. If you then point your browser to http://localhost:8080/, you will see in the console:

```
I need access to the HTTP headers: null
```

## working solution, by bypassing Jersey and using `HttpServletRequest`

I tried wiring `HttpServletRequest` in the aspect and then accessing the `Authorization` header:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(so.MyAnnotation)")
    public void annotated() {
    }

    @Before("annotated()")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(request.getHeader("authorization"));
    }
}
```

I also added to `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This basically bypasses Jersey completely. This seems to work, I can now read out the `Authorization` header in the aspect. Great!

But, my question still stands: is there a way to inject Jersey's context objects into a Spring-managed aspect?

Comment: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` gives access to the `Authentication` object . Is this what you are looking for ? [SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) associates a given SecurityContext with the current execution thread.

Comment: I am not using the `spring-security` project, so I cannot use `SecurityContextHolder`. My question is not necessarily about just accessing the `Authorization` header (which I guess `SecurityContextHolder` does), but rather about getting access to the Jersey contextual objects in the aspect implementation. Keep in mind I am using Jersey/JAX-RS (and not Spring MVC).

Comment: Oh ok , I understand .With pure `aspectj` it should be possible. If you wish you may add the tag to get the right attention. Also a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help the experts who are not spring devs to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added the `aspectj` tag to my question. I also added a minimal example which demonstrates my question. See update of my question, at the very bottom.

Comment: I also added a working solution which bypasses Jersey. I am still curious if it's possible to autowire Jersey's objects into Spring's beans.

Comment: Any solution to this?